# R -- Expand date range into panel data by group

Tags: r, date, seq

I have date ranges that are grouped by two variables (`id` and `type`) that are currently stored in a data frame called `data`. My goal is to expand the date range such that I have a row for each day within the range of dates, which includes the same `id` and `type`.

Here is a snippet to reproduce an example of the data frame:

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), type = c("a", 
"a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f"), from = structure(c(1235199600, 
1235545200, 1235545200, 1235631600, 1235631600, 1242712800, 1242712800, 
1243058400, 1243058400, 1243231200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), to = structure(c(1235372400, 1235545200, 1235631600, 
1235890800, 1236236400, 1242712800, 1243058400, 1243231200, 1243144800, 
1243576800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("id", 
"type", "from", "to"), row.names = c(700L, 753L, 2941L, 2178L, 
 2959L, 679L, 2185L, 12L, 802L, 1796L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a visual representation of the data set:

```
id  type  from        to
1   a     2009-02-21  2009-02-23
1   a     2009-02-25  2009-02-25
1   b     2009-02-25  2009-02-26
1   c     2009-02-25  2009-03-01
1   b     2009-05-26  2009-03-05
2   a     2009-05-26  2009-05-19
2   c     2009-05-19  2009-05-23
2   d     2009-05-19  2009-05-25
2   e     2009-05-23  2009-05-24
2   f     2009-05-25  2009-05-29
```

Here is a visual representation of the intended result:

```
id  type  date
1   a     2009-02-21
1   a     2009-02-22
1   a     2009-02-23
1   b     2009-02-25
1   b     2009-02-26
1   c     2009-02-26
1   c     2009-02-27
1   c     2009-02-28
1   c     2009-03-01
...
2   f     2009-05-25
2   f     2009-05-26
2   f     2009-05-27
2   f     2009-05-28
2   f     2009-05-29
```

I've found several similar posts ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067478/expand-unbalanced-data-to-monthly-panel) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expanding-a-sequence-in-a-data-frame)) that were helpful in giving me a starting point.  I've attempted to use a plyr solution:

```
data2 <- adply(data, 1, summarise, date = seq(data$from, data$to))[c('id', 'type')]
```

However, this results in the error:

```
Error: 'from' must be of length 1
```

I have also attempted to use a data.table solution:

```
data[, list(date = seq(from, to)), by = c('id', 'type')]
```

However, this gives me a different error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , list(date = seq(from, to)), by = c("id",  : 
unused argument (by = c("id", "type"))
```

Any thoughts on how to go about resolving these errors (or using a different approach) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1) by** Here is a three line answer using `by` from the base of R.  First we convert the dates to `"Date"` class giving `data2`.  Then we apply `f` which does the real work over each row and finally we `rbind` the resulting rows together:

```
data2 <- transform(data, from = as.Date(from), to = as.Date(to))

f <- function(x) with(x, data.frame(id, type, date = seq(from, to, by = "day")))
do.call("rbind", by(data, 1:nrow(data), f))
```

**2) data.table** Using the same `data2` with data.table we do it like this:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(data2)
dt[, list(id, type, date = seq(from, to, by = "day")), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
```

**2a) data.table** or alternately this where `dt` is from (2) and `f` is from (1):

```
dt[, f(.SD), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
```

**3) dplyr** Here `data2` and `f` are from (1):

```
data2 %>% rowwise %>% do(f(.)) %>% ungroup
```

**4) dplyr/purrr**  Here `data2` is from (1).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data2 %>%
  pmap(function(..., from, to) tibble(..., date = seq(from, to, by = "day"))) %>%
  bind_rows
```

**UPDATES** Some improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to perform such a transformation using base functions

```
do.call(rbind,Map(function(id,type,from,to) {
    dts <- seq(from=from, to=to, by="1 day")
    dur <- length(dts)
    data.frame(
        id=rep(id, dur), 
        type=rep(type,dur),
        date=dts
    )
}, data$id, data$type, data$from, data$to))
```

And the first chunck of the output is

```
   id type                date
1   1    a 2009-02-21 02:00:00
2   1    a 2009-02-22 02:00:00
3   1    a 2009-02-23 02:00:00
4   1    a 2009-02-25 02:00:00
5   1    b 2009-02-25 02:00:00
6   1    b 2009-02-26 02:00:00
7   1    c 2009-02-26 02:00:00
8   1    c 2009-02-27 02:00:00
9   1    c 2009-02-28 02:00:00
10  1    c 2009-03-01 02:00:00
11  1    b 2009-02-26 02:00:00
```