# Expand start and end dates to unbalanced monthly panel with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyverse

I have start and end dates for events that I want to expand into a monthly panel, and I wanted to know if there was any tool in `dplyr` for solving this problem. The following code does what I want to do with `ddply()`. It first creates an example `tibble` `data.frame` (called "wide") where "id" represents an individual and "HomeNum" is an event for that individual. The next line creates a "date" variable that is a monthly series from "StartDate" to "FinishDate" within each "id" by "HomeNum" group.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
wide = 
    tibble(
        id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
        HomeNum = c(0,1,0,1,2),
        StartDate = as.Date(c("2001-01-01", "2001-03-01", "2000-04-01", "2001-02-01", "2002-08-01")),
        FinishDate = as.Date(c("2001-02-01", "2002-05-01", "2001-01-01", "2002-07-01", "2002-12-01"))
    )
panel = 
    ddply(wide, 
          ~id+HomeNum, 
          transform, 
          date = seq.Date(StartDate, FinishDate, by = "month")
    )
```

I assume that `dplyr`, as the "the next iteration of `plyr`", must have some way to implement a similar solution (and output a `tibble`), but the following did not work:

```
panel = 
    wide %>% 
    group_by(id, HomeNum) %>% 
    mutate(date = seq.Date(StartDate, FinishDate, by = "month"))
```

and returned

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
    Column `date` must be length 1 (the group size), not 2
```

Frankly, I am surprised that the `ddply()` solution works and does not throw a similar error.

My implementation with `ddply()` is similar to answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067478/expand-unbalanced-data-to-monthly-panel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can coerce the elements of `date` to lists and `unnest`.

```
library(tidyverse)
wide %>%
  group_by(id, HomeNum) %>%
  mutate(date = list(seq.Date(StartDate, FinishDate, by = "month"))) %>%
  unnest(date)
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I get "Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames".

Comment: Unnesting lists of dates is an issue in `tidyr` that should be fixed in the most recent version(s). Referenced [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/407). I got this error, updated to 0.8.1, and no longer get it, but will post a workaround

Answer (score 3):

Using `unnest` on a list of dates was an issue in previous versions of `tidyr`. I got this same error and found a workaround, but then no longer needed the workaround once I updated to `tidyr` 0.8.1. It's an issue that's documented in a few issues on GitHub—[#407](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/407) and [#450](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/450) were ones I looked at.

If you have a version that can't unnest dates, you can build on @hpesoj626's answer by converting the dates to strings, unnesting, then converting the strings back to dates.

```r
library(tidyverse)

wide <- tibble(
    id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
    HomeNum = c(0,1,0,1,2),
    StartDate = as.Date(c("2001-01-01", "2001-03-01", "2000-04-01", "2001-02-01", "2002-08-01")),
    FinishDate = as.Date(c("2001-02-01", "2002-05-01", "2001-01-01", "2002-07-01", "2002-12-01"))
  )

# with previous versions of tidyr
wide %>%
  group_by(id, HomeNum) %>%
  mutate(date = list(seq.Date(StartDate, FinishDate, by = "month") %>% as.character())) %>%
  tidyr::unnest() %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
#> # A tibble: 50 x 5
#> # Groups:   id, HomeNum [5]
#>       id HomeNum StartDate  FinishDate date      
#>    <dbl>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>    
#>  1     1       0 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 2001-01-01
#>  2     1       0 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 2001-02-01
#>  3     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-03-01
#>  4     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-04-01
#>  5     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-05-01
#>  6     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-06-01
#>  7     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-07-01
#>  8     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-08-01
#>  9     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-09-01
#> 10     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-10-01
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

Otherwise, a solution like the one they posted should work:

```r
# with tidyr 0.8.1
wide %>%
  group_by(id, HomeNum) %>%
  mutate(date = list(seq.Date(StartDate, FinishDate, by = "month"))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest()
#> # A tibble: 50 x 5
#> # Groups:   id, HomeNum [5]
#>       id HomeNum StartDate  FinishDate date      
#>    <dbl>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>    
#>  1     1       0 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 2001-01-01
#>  2     1       0 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 2001-02-01
#>  3     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-03-01
#>  4     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-04-01
#>  5     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-05-01
#>  6     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-06-01
#>  7     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-07-01
#>  8     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-08-01
#>  9     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-09-01
#> 10     1       1 2001-03-01 2002-05-01 2001-10-01
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

Another option is to `gather` the data into a long format, where observations have a `type` column showing whether it's the start or finish date. Then use `complete` to fill in missing dates between each group's minimum and maximum dates. Gathering keeps the `type` column, which gets filled in as `NA` for the dates that are added. You could then drop the `type` column if it's no longer useful.

```r
wide %>%
  gather(key = type, value = date, StartDate, FinishDate) %>%
  group_by(id, HomeNum) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by = "month"))
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#> # Groups:   id, HomeNum [5]
#>       id HomeNum date       type      
#>    <dbl>   <dbl> <date>     <chr>     
#>  1     1       0 2001-01-01 StartDate 
#>  2     1       0 2001-02-01 FinishDate
#>  3     1       1 2001-03-01 StartDate 
#>  4     1       1 2001-04-01 <NA>      
#>  5     1       1 2001-05-01 <NA>      
#>  6     1       1 2001-06-01 <NA>      
#>  7     1       1 2001-07-01 <NA>      
#>  8     1       1 2001-08-01 <NA>      
#>  9     1       1 2001-09-01 <NA>      
#> 10     1       1 2001-10-01 <NA>      
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

Created on 2018-05-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I edited your 0.8,1 solution to remove the `= as.Date(date)` from the `mutate()` function, as date was already stored as a Date in that version. Also, is there any benefit to the second `mutate()` function? The code seems to have the same output without it.

Comment: @randy thanks for catching that, the second mutate was left over from debugging with the earlier version